# explain please how in the given block of code => get values from two variables and print the similar values ... beginner level

Tags: python

block of code is:

```
from pcinput import getString

word1 = getString( "Give word 1: " )
word2 = getString( "Give word 2: " )
common = ""
for letter in word1:
    if (letter in word2) and (letter not in common):
        common += letter
if common == "":
    print( "The words share no characters." )
else:
    print( "The words have the following in common:", common )
```

Execution gives:
"Give word 1: *ready*
Give word 2: *steady*
The words have the following in common: *eady*"

What I don't understand is the following part:
    *for letter in word1:
        if (letter in word2) and (letter not in common):
            common += letter*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. We start by declaring an empty string `common`. As we find letters the two words have in common, we will add them to this string.
2. `for letter in word1`: We go through the first word letter by letter.
3. `if (letter in word2) and (letter not in common)`: We check if the letter is also in the second word or also already stored in `common`.
4. `common += letter`: We append the letter to our string. Since we check `common` for our letter in the previous step, the final result of `common` will only ever contain a maximum of one of each letter.

Comment: now I understand > the code takes each value of variable letter ONE BY ONE as in example / "banana" x 2 / only ban is in variable common at the end of the loop since:                                                                                            a) "b" then "a" then "n" are both part of word1 and word2                                                                                                 b) the second "a" violates the logic of the if statement because the "a" is already in variable common // Thanks also kylew and Simeon > your answers also added to understand the logic :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
for letter in word1:
    if (letter in word2) and (letter not in common):
        common += letter
```

All this code is doing is using a for loop to go through each character in word1 (using "letter" as the name of that character) and adds it to the string common if it's also in word2 and if it's not already in common (since common just contains the letters in both strings, no duplicates).

For more information about for loops in Python, perhaps see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html